# Can observables be used in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, promise, observable

Asynchronous control mechanisms have evolved from callbacks, to promises (async/await), and now to observables.

Is there an ES implementation of observables, and if not, is there another way to use observables in nodeJS applications?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html

Comment: @cartant I don't think the OP is referring to the rx library

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration#implementation-status?

Comment: Of possible interest [What are the differences between observables and promises in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064303/what-are-the-differences-between-observables-and-promises-in-javascript)

Comment: I should have included more than just a link in the above comment. The linked-to RxJS library contains an `Observable` implementation compliant with the [observable proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable).

Comment: @Bergi Why do you think that? Do you think he's asking about the implementation status of the Stage 1 proposal for native Observables which is not implemented anywhere AFAIK?

Comment: @torazaburo TBH I have no idea what he is asking about.

Comment: @Bergi Well, it seems (to me) very likely that he wants to use Observables in node, which is a trivial matter with rxjs.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, it's so trivial that I wonder whether he meant those, given that the question seems to assume there might be a reason not to be able to use them. Also the talk about "callbacks" and "promises" led me to believe he means standard implementations.

Comment: @torazaburo  yes ! I want to use observables in Node . First i was using callbacks then i used promises now l i was just thinking to use obsevables (rxjs) or Native es6 . So that it can replace Promises. Can it possible ? If yes then how can i use in Node.

Answer (score 3):

Just use rxjs in the normal way.

```
$ mkdir rxjs-test && cd rxjs-test
$ npm install rxjs
$ node -e "require('rxjs').Observable.of(1).subscribe(console.log);"
1
$ node -e "require('rxjs').Observable.interval(1000).take(5).subscribe(console.log);"
0
1
2
3
4
$
```

You're aware, of course, that observables are not a one-to-one replacement for promises. Promises represent a single future value; observables represent a stream of future values.

Answer (score 2):

As far as node support for ES Observables goes, you'll find that as of this writing there is no support yet. You can check [here](http://node.green/#ESNEXT-proposal--stage-1--Observable) for the latest status of Observable support in node.

Comment: Sure, there are no native Observables, in node or for that matter in any browser, but `rxjs` should work just fine, or am I missing something?

Comment: @torazaburo the question was not tagged with react and/or similar tags, so I assumed they were referring to ES Observables.